# Delete method does not work, Couldn't find Booking with 'id'=15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I created a web application where an user can book a hour of training. I want this application to let the user delete the book if it wants. When i get to the unbook button it shows an error that says:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#destroy
>
> Couldn't find Booking with 'id'=14

I would like to know why is this happening and how i can fix it so the delete of the booking is succesfully done.

Booking controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
    @booking.training_id
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Reservacion creada"
      redirect_to trainings_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.where(training_id: params[:training_id])
  end


  def destroy
    Booking.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Reservacion eliminada"
    redirect_to trainings_path
  end

private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:id, :user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end
end
```

Training show:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.left_slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>

    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
    </center>
```

Booking_form:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <% if current_user.not_booked?(@training) %>
    <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training),
        class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(@training),
        method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'You sure?' },
        class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

config.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :users
  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
end
```

Training model:

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

  def can_book?
    bookings.count < slots
  end

  def left_slots
    slots - bookings.count
  end
end
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true
  validate :training_not_full?, on: :create



private

  def training_not_full?
    errors.add(:base, :full, message: "Full training") unless training.can_book?
  end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trainings, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

    def not_booked?(training)
      bookings.where(training: training).none?
    end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your `Training` and `Booking` models?

Comment: Great, thanks, could you also show the `User` model? I want to see the `not_booked?` method.

Comment: Updated with the User model!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested route. You need to specify both the training and the booking in order to delete. Instead of...

```
<%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(@training),
    method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'You sure?' },
    class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Do...

```
<%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(@training, @training.bookings.where(user: current_user).first,
    method: :delete, data:{ confirm: 'You sure?' },
    class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Comment: it gives me the following error now: Couldn't find Booking with 'id'=#<Booking::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc57448a850>

Comment: A `training` can have many `bookings`. `Training` is the parent resource and `booking` is the nested(child) resource. What do you think `@training.booking` will return?

Comment: Ah, right, but you didn't use the convention of the plural `bookings` ?  Anyway, my edited answer should work. Let me know if that works for you. .  Ideally that relation should be extracted into a model method (e.g. `@training.booking_for_user(@user)` but you can do that in a refactor.

Comment: Your solution is still wrong, I am not sure why it was upvoted. It should be `@training.bookings.where(user: @user).first`. A `training` has many `bookings`. So, every `training` instance gets a `bookings` method dynamically created. I am pretty sure `@training` does not respond to `booking` method. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: ok i did it exactly as you said and now its showing this error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookings", :id=>nil, :training_id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: By the way, i used training_booking_path(@training, @training.bookings.where(user: @user).first) instead of @training.booking.where

Comment: @SteveTurczyn By the way, can you explain why you pick the first booking? `@training.booking.where(user: @user).first`?

Comment: @ArunKumar based on the fact the OP got a collection proxy using the original answer which had a singular `booking` it means the OP didn't follow convention and probably has "has_many booking` which is unconventional but possible..   Cesar, please post your models Training and Booking so we can see how the relationships are defined.

Comment: @ArunKumar because I used `where`... I expect only one record returned but it would be in a collection so I want the first (and only) record.  Alternatively, I could have used `find_by` which might have been better. Until we clearly understand how the relationships are defined it's moot.

Comment: Updated! I tried to use find_by and it worked in development but when i pushed it to heroku (production) it did not work.

Comment: Hi, please try my edited code.  I realise now that the booking is for `current_user` not `@user` and I've fixed that, and I'm using the correct plurals `bookings`.   That should work now (fingers crossed).

Answer (score 0):

In your bookings form you only send the id of the **Training**, not the **Booking**.
Therefor it tries to delete a book with the id of the Training. You should send both the id of the training and the booking.

If you do `rake routes` you will have a route like this:

```
DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#destroy
```

That expects both a training id and a booking id.

```
<%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(@training, <the booking object>),
```

If a training have multiple bookings, you will have to decide how you system should decide what booking to delete. @training.bookings.first, will most likely return the first booking.

Comment: so you are saying i should change the @training for @booking?

Comment: when you say <the booking object> what you mean? because i think thats the training (since user wants to book in a training)

Answer (score 0):

Since `booking` is a nested resource(depends on `training`), you need to pass both the ids of `@training` and `@booking` to the url helper.

```
<%= link_to "Unbook", training_booking_path(@training), method: :delete %>
```

In the above code snippet, the url should be `training_booking_path(@training, @booking)` or you could even simplify it as

```
<%= link_to "Unbook", [@training, @booking], method: :delete %>
```

(the `data` and `class` options are excluded for brevity)

Make sure that `@booking` is defined in the controller action responsible for the view that displays the link.

Rails will infer that you're trying to send a `DELETE` request to `/trainings/#{@training.id}/bookings/#{@booking.id}` based on the `method: :delete` option and the target `[@training, @booking]`

You can find the exact path by running `rake routes` and you should find the following entry:

```
DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id bookings#destroy
```

So, in the `destroy` method, you can find the `booking` using

```
# in bookings_controller.rb

class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_training # you need to find the training before performing any action

  # other actions

  def destroy
    @booking = @training.bookings.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    # flash setting & redirect
  end

  private

  def set_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end
```

To know more about routing nested resources, read the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: when i do this, it shows an error that says destroy is not defined in the training controller

Comment: @CesarBrazon Can you paste the code you tried in the comment below? And also, did you define `@comment` in the controller method responsible for displaying the unbook link?

Comment: no i did not define the @comment, what this variable is?

Comment: @CesarBrazon My bad. It should've been `@booking`(got mixed up). Did you define the `@booking` instance variable in the controller? Sorry for the confusion. Btw, please post the code you tried so that I can figure out what's wrong